# FAILED (remote: Partition should be flashed in fastbootd) PIXEL 3XL Android 11 FAILED (remote: 'Operation not permitted')

Tags: adb, fastboot

Could someone help me with the following problem:

I want to flash my pixel 3XL with AOSP precompiled images in ***android 11***, but it gives me this error:

[image]

I have fastboot **version 1: 8.1.0 + r23-5 ~ 18.04**
and adb version:
Android Debug **Bridge version 1.0.39**
Version **1: 8.1.0 + r23-5 ~ 18.04**

I have a problem when executing fastboot flash on my pixel 3xl, it returns the following error:

**Writing sparse 'system_a' 4/6                      FAILED (remote: 'Operation not permitted')**

[image]

someone help me with this error.